# display 1st image inside id

Tags: javascript, jquery

Interested to know if I can use jQuery to find the first image on the page and display it inside a  resized to a thumbnail with click to enlarge. For example, on this particular blog, when the client adds an image to the post, jQuery will find the first image, display it as a clickable thumbnail in a particular location. It would be ideal if the detailed image could display in thickbox, facebox or another jQuery overlay window.

Thanks in advance for your ideas.
Jackson

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`:first`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/first) selector to find the first image, then using cloning you can copy the image to any other location and modify it from there.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var firstImage = $('img:first');
    var link = $('<a />')
                    .attr('href', '#')
                    .append($('img:first').clone().css({ width:100, height:100 }))
                    .append($('<div />').text('Click to Enlarge'))
                    .click(function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        // showDialog();
                    });
    $('.imageThumbnail').append(link);

    $('.imageDialog').append(firstImage.clone());

});
```

Comment: Wouldn't cloning be somewhat of an overkill (especially when done twice) when all that's being persisted is the image's src?

Comment: you're only cloning the HTML.  IMHO the impact would be minimal

Answer (score 1):

To find the first image in your page you can use the **[:first](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/first)** selector.

`$("img:first")` will select the first img element.

If you want to restrict the search within a parent element then you can

```
$("#parentElemId").find("img:first")
```

If you can give these image elements a class name then you can do

```
$("img.classname:first")
```

Comment: when restricting using the second option why not use `#parentElemId img:first` or `#parentElemId > img:first`?

Comment: Good point bendeway. $("#parentid img:first") is much cleaner.

Comment: The method that @pulse provided shows a useful optimization if you plan on doing something else with the parent node.  For example, `var n = $("#parentElemId"); ... n.find("img:first");`.

Answer (score 1):

Like other members have mentioned you can get the first image by using img:first. The simplest way to display it as a thumbnail would be:

```
$(document).append("<img src='" + $("img:first").attr("src") + "' alt='' class='thickbox' style='width: 50px; height: 50px;' />");
```

The `class='thickbox'` part is for the [thickbox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/) plugin

Here's a more specific sample based on your comment:

If the original data looks something like this:

```
<div id="thumbs"></div>
<div id="article">
    <img src="..." alt="" />
    Some text..
</div>
```

You can use something like this:

```
var images = "";

$("#article img:first").each(function() {
    images += "<img src='" + $(this).attr('src') + "' width='45' class='thickbox' alt='Click to enlarge' /> ";
});

$("#thumbs").append(images);
```

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but I can't see from your code where the image would be appended to?

Comment: In the sample the image would simply be appended to the document meaning it'll appear as the first item. You can easily change that by replacing document with any valid selector for the parent element

Comment: Thanks Ariel. I will be using this on a blog with several article intro's. Each article intro will contain an image: <div class="intro"><div class="thumbcontainer"></div><img src="bigimage.jpg">Content here</div>. Being new to jQuery it is hard for me to see how to I would use your code to find the images in each intro on the page and append to the .thumbcontainer of each intro so each intro has a thumbnail. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: @Jackson - I've updated the answer with a more specific sample based on your comment. I'm assuming there's only one thumbcontainer for the whole document and not one for each, that's why I included a sample of what the actual source should look like...